# Chrome doesn't execute jquery function after refresh but does when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Hello I have another odd problem. I have a jquery function that proportionally resizes images. It works however on chrome when I refresh the page it doesnt completely work. Let me explain. If you hit the homepage link it works and all images are resized. If you refresh the page some or none of the images are resized. This only happens in chrome. It doesnt happen in firefox.

Here is the jquery

```
$.fn.imageResize = function(options) {
    var settings = {
        width: 400,
        height: 222
    };

    options = $.extend(settings, options);

    return this.each(function() {
        var $element = $(this);
        var maxWidth = options.width;
        var maxHeight = options.height;
        var ratio = 0;
        var width = $element.width();
        var height = $element.height();

        if ( width > maxWidth ) {
            ratio = maxWidth / width;

            $element.css("width", maxWidth);
            $element.css("height", height * ratio);
        }

        if (height > maxHeight) {
            ratio = maxHeight / height;

            $element.css("height", maxHeight);
            $element.css("width", width * ratio);
        }
    });
}
```

My header includes the necessary stuff

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/core/views/js/image-resize.js">   </script>
```

Then I call the function on the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').imageResize();
    });
</script>

<img src="" alt="">
```

So if you load the page by going through a link the code works and the images are resize proportionally. If you hit f5 or the refresh button the code doesn't work and images appear in their original size.

Is there a way to ensure the code will execute on chrome properly?

Comment: Is this executed in other browsers? and have you tried to add a timeout for the resize function like this timeout(function(){$('img').imageResize();}, 5000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `.imageResize()` too early, because  `$(document).ready()` fires before content has finished loading. The method runs but does not find valid targets.

Bind it on window `load` and it will most likely work as expected:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
   $('img').imageResize();
})
```